# How do I use a dedicated mini?

Tags: guild-wars

I'm returning after many years and have forgotten everything. Is there mini inventory? Can't seem to find information on this. Where can I select the one I want to use?

Comment: You are talking about Guild Wars 1 and not Guild Wars 2, right? Just to be sure not to type an answer for the bad one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mini inventory in Guild Wars 1. The only thing you can do is having your mini in your inventory and double-clicking it to make it appear in your instance.

Comment: Yes GW1. Thank you for replying!  I've read that dedicated minis can be "used" by anyone. If the icon is not in my inventory, how do I switch them?

Comment: @user175790 That's the opposite. When you dedicated your mini (that you put it in the Hall of Monuments), it can't be traded to anyone else anymore. If you didn't dedicate your mini, you can still trade it to anyone. Anyway, imagining your other mini is, for instance, in your Xunlai Chest, you simply have to drag and drop it in your inventory, and then double-click to use it.

Comment: I'm playing on my husband's old account. The inventory is mostly full and I don't know what to keep or get rid of. I didn't see any minis in the Xunlai Chest but I will check other characters' inventory. But if the mini icon has been deleted, can they still be switched? I'm not trying to trade them, just "equip" them.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user175790 You're welcome. Well, you can't "equip" them. The only way to make them appear is to double-click them in your inventory, even if the icon is missing. It should make it appear in your instance after using it this way. If you double-click another mini after this, it will just be switched in the instance. You can switch them as many times you want to.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a [miniature](https://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Miniature) (commonly known as a "mini" or "minipet") in your inventory or storage in Guild Wars, you can double click on it to activate or deactivate it. When active, a miniature will follow you around, but will not affect combat in any way. You can only have one miniature active at a time, and no miniatures will be active when you load into an instance.

There is no miniature inventory in Guild Wars, but they can be placed in any inventory or bank slot, except for [equipment packs](https://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Equipment_Pack).

All miniatures are initially undedicated ("unded"), and can be added to the [Devotion](https://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/%22Devotion%22) monument in the [Hall of Monuments](https://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Hall_of_Monuments) ("HoM"). Once a miniature has been dedicated to *any* character's Hall of Monuments, that miniature is permanently marked as "Dedicated" ("ded") and cannot be added to another Hall of Monuments. Dedicated miniatures can still be traded and used by any character.